# Hooks in FeathersJS or Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js, hook, feathersjs

Given the scenario I want to insert a default value in a database column (date_introduced). I'm considering two alternatives:

- use a hook in sequelize (hook: beforeCreate)
- use a hook in feathersJS (hook: create)

What would be the specific benefits for each alternative? But of course there are other scenario's like checking on an input, etc... each with their own concerns.

Comment: Can't you add defaultValue option in column from any DB GUI or even in Sequelize model definition for the column which you want to have a default value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a simple migration for your Sequelize DB.

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.changeColumn('tableName', 'columnName', {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      defaultValue: <defaultValue>
    });
  },

  down: function (queryInterface, Sequelize) {
    return queryInterface.changeColumn('tableName', 'columnName', {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
      defaultValue: null
    });
  }
};
```

You can find more info in [official documentation of feathers.](https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-sequelize#migrations)